# How to make a VoIP from receiving Raw Notification Windows Phone

Tags: windows-phone, voip, skype, background-agent

I've read this topic
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj206983%28v=vs.105%29.aspx

And my knowledge I understand is that Server will send a Raw Notification ( with X-Class = 4 )
to Front-End(Windows Phone apps). 
Assume that my app is deactivate(it means that my device is on Lock Screen). And my question is how to make a VoIP incoming call(on client side) when Server send a Raw Notification to my WP device?
To make another VoIP application, which functions or module do I have to consider in this project? 
I want to create an application that is same as Skype or Whatapps.
Please help me.
Thanks in advance!